# Enable one column on change of another column in jquery

Tags: jquery

My rows in table is below.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Site1</td>
    <td>
    <select class="countryList"  
            name="countryList" 
            onchange="toggleVisibility(this);">
           <option value=""></option>
            <option value="country1" selected>country1</option>
            <option value="country2" >country2</option>
   </select>
  </td>
   <td>
    <select class="stateList"  
            name="stateList" 
            >
           <option value=""></option>
            <option value="state1" disabled>state1</option>
            <option value="state2" disabled>state2</option>
            <option value="state3" disabled>state3</option>

            </select>

   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Site2</td>
<td>
    <select class="countryList"  
            name="countryList" 
            onchange="toggleVisibility(this);">
           <option value=""></option>
            <option value="country1" >country1</option>
            <option value="country2" selected>country2</option>
   </select>
  </td>
   <td>
    <select class="stateList"  
            name="stateList" 
            >
           <option value=""></option>
            <option value="state1" selected>state1</option>
            <option value="state2" >state2</option>
            <option value="state3" >state3</option>

            </select>

   </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Here  `toggleVisibility` method should enable the visibility of `stateList`. I have written below.

```
function toggleVisibility(element){
                var country = $(element).attr("value");
                if(country == 'US'){
                    $(element).next().attr("disabled", false);
                    }else $(element).next().attr("disabled", true);
            }
```

But i am getting javascript error that `$(element).next().attr` not defined. Please point me my error.Suggest me good documentaiton on JQuery table manipulation. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You realise that jQuery works client-side, don't you? This means that the server side code, including `<c:forEach items="${Countries}" var="country">`, has almost **no** relevance to your question. Posting the actual, generated mark-up as seen by the browser (`view source`, copy and paste the relevant `table`) is *far*, **far** more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `$(element).next().attr(...)` is not defined is because [`$(element).next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) returns an empty jQuery result.  `next()` returns the element's next immediate sibling, and in this case there is none.

You could modify your code to select the `stateList` `select` directly:

```
function toggleVisibility(element){
    var country = element.value;
    $("select[name='stateList']").attr("disabled", country == 'US');
}
```

**Update:** Or you could more generically find the "next" select in the row:

```
function toggleVisibility(element){
    var country = element.value;
    $(element).closest("td").next().find("select").attr("disabled", country == 'US');
}
```

This finds the adjacent `td`'s `select` and disable it.  If you want to get more specific you could use `select[name='stateList']` instead.

I've also removed the `if/else` block in favor of putting the boolean expression directly in the call to `attr()`.

Side note: Setting the `disabled` property on a form element doesn't toggle visibility, it just enables or disables user input on that form field.

If you wanted to show/hide the form field based on the value of `countryList`, you could use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
function toggleVisibility(element){
    var country = element.value;
    $("select[name='stateList']").toggle(country == 'US');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Output html is: row1: country1 state1 Row2:country2 state2. If we refer country1..next should be state1. How come this will return null value. ( i dont know much ..but as next suggests sibling..it should state1). If we seelct as suggested, is it points to that row only ?

Comment: That's not the case because of `<td>` elements which wrap table data.  If you had two elements in the same `<td>`, `next()` would work like you expect it to.

Comment: This is applying to all rows. But i want disable/enable only particular row. How to select stateList value corresponing country row?